# Is there a word that means "blaring" but in a good way?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective that describes the sound of a marching band that plays really loud and energetic and you like it.

If you hated the music, it would be "blaring", because it's way too loud. But since you are a fan of marching bands, you actually love the obnoxiously loud and intrusive sound.  So, if you wanted to say

> There was one ____ marching band after another in the parade.

What word would you use to fill in the blank?

**Edit:**

The ideal word would be an old-fashioned one that was probably cool 80 years ago like "rootin'-tootin'".

"Thundering" is great but I feel it implies the sound has a lot of bass whereas the brass band in question would sound more high-pitched and piercing. But I ended up using "thundering" anyway, because I like the boisterous feel of the word and the deadline is coming to get me :)

Comment: Are you looking for something formal, or more colloquial/slangy? There are a lot of slang terms associated with enjoying loud music, but most aren't suitable for formal writing. Also a lot of multi-word expressions that might not fit in your blank but would be fine in contexts like "That music was _" or "That music _"; would you consider one of them. (Sadly I can't find *block-rocking* in dictionaries.)

Comment: @StuartF I really needed an adjective to be used in the sentence in my original post but if you have any other interesting expressions, shoot, I may use them next time I'm translating something about a marching band :)

Comment: According to AHDEL, the noun _tantara_ can means "a trumpet or horn fanfare" or "a sound resembling such a fanfare." So you could render it as a modifier as **tantaraing**. At least [one modern author](https://books.google.com/books?id=fHMhAQAAIAAJ&q=%22tantara-ing%22&dq=%22tantara-ing%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSmqLzvPf5AhXUL0QIHXLSBUMQ6AF6BAgDEAI) has done so. But **fanfaring** might be a more accessible option; AHDEL defines the noun _fanfare_ as "a loud flourish of brass instruments, especially trumpets." Even simpler and potentially on point is **brassy**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that even *blaring* could take on positive connotations if used in the right context, in the same way you would call your group of friends ***gang*** for example, without meaning anything negative.

But if you *must* avoid *blaring*, you could use ***thundering***, which bears the connotation of *loud*, but also *impressive* noise:

> very loud:
>
> - The show will be set to ***thundering** music*.([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thundering))

> making a resounding, loud, deep noise.
>
> - thundering waterfalls ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=thundering%20meaning&hl=en&sxsrf=ALiCzsYv-WJOZqQTceS4AqXgRY_Q3ws5Sg%3A1662121816383&source=hp&ei=WPcRY8yEFaSZhbIPgNqpwA0&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYxIFaPW0zTUcthywZUO_XFEHdGDj1FnF&oq=&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJ1AAWABgvg9oAXAAeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQCwAQo&sclient=gws-wiz))

> awesomely great, intense, or unusual ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thundering))